# Meaning of the verb "cut" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology, slang

Here is the context:

> High intensity interval training can be used to lose as much fat as possible while **cutting**, to stay lean and conditioned while adding muscle, or to improve aerobic and anaerobic endurance for performance-focused athletes.

Does it mean while trying to get muscle definition?

Comment: This use of `cutting` is not standard English, but jargon, argot, or bizspeak. Without object, it is difficult to imagine what is being stated.

Comment: You will also hear it (in AmE) as an adjective: *After six weeks of grueling pre-season training, the whole team was looking really **cut***.  where it means "having a lean body with 'sculpted' muscles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fitness world jargon "**cutting**" means fat loss, "but
it also emphasizes the fact that you've built muscle before and now
you're burning fat while adding definition to your muscles."

From [Gymaholic site](https://www.gymaholic.co/articles/cutting-guide):

> Definition Of A Cut A lot of people don't understand the fitness terms
>   cut and bulking:
>
> Bulking: It means increasing your caloric intake (caloric surplus), in
>   order to build muscle.
>
> **Cutting**: It's when you want to lose the fat you accumulated during
>   your bulk, so you do a caloric deficit during a certain period of
>   time.
>
> **"What's the difference between a fat loss and a cut?" In fact, none**.
>   Cut is simply the term used by fitness lovers just after a bulk. But
>   it also emphasizes the fact that you've built muscle before and now
>   you're burning fat while adding definition to your muscles.